# Find the absolute extrema of the function over the region R

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the absolute extrema of the function over the region R

where $f(x,y)=x^2+xy, R=\{(x,y)|\;|x|\leq2,|y|\leq1\}$,

Here find we going find $f_x=2x+y=0, f_y=x=0 \Rightarrow (x,y)=(0,0)$ is i am right? then how we going to processed this problem for further

Comment: @David..thanks i did

Answer (score 1):

You have $f(0,0)=0$ as one potential extremum.  Now you also need to check the boundaries of the region.  For example: if $x=2$ then
$$f(x,y)=f(2,y)=4+2y\ ,\quad -1\le y\le1\ ,$$
and this gives you two more potential extrema,
$$f(2,-1)=2\quad\hbox{and}\quad f(2,1)=6\ .$$
The boundary is a rectangle so there are three more sides to investigate.  I'll leave this to you.

Comment: ..thnks..bu i am not understand please can you explain little more\

Comment: You have to check the boundaries of the region as well as the interior.

Comment: u mean i need to find the find extream when x=-2,1,-1

Comment: $x=-2$ yes, $x=\pm1$ no.  Look more carefully at the region.